# Is there a word to describe things that do not follow a rule

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word (preferably an adjective) to describe things that do not follow a rule?

For example if the rule is: no object heavier than 200lb is allowed inside a building. How would I reference all the objects that aren't compliant to that rule in a sentence like the one below.

`These are all the _____ objects`

Comment: ***exceptions***.

Comment: More context, please. These objects could be ***unregulated*** or ***unclassifiable***, for example.

Comment: The *objects that aren't compliant* are just ***non-compliant** objects*.

Comment: *These are all the offending objects*

Comment: Part of the problem is that things are not responsible for following rules. I would reference the trait in question. "These are all the overweight objects." If the criteria were more complex, "These are the objects of concern."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say the hyphenated compound word: *non-conforming* is the best choice for the example...

> *These are all the non-conforming objects.*

Comment: +1 a Good offering. But *the best choice*?

Answer (score 2):

If they're specially allowed to circumvent the rules, you could describe them as **exempt**:

> *adjective*
>   released from, or not subject to, an obligation, liability

[Source: Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/exempt)

It works in your example:

> These are all the *exempt* objects

Answer (score 2):

It depends.  Not being compliant implies that they're not following the rules.  In that case, you could say they're **rogue**.  If they are an exception to the rule (meaning, the rule doesn't apply to them), then you could say **exempt**.  You could also say *"These are all the non-compliant objects."*

Comment: +1 Rogue is my favorite...it just sounds like "In your face! I'm not following the rules!" :-)

Answer (score 2):

An [outlier](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/outlier) is a thing or measurement which differs significantly from the others in its set:

> a statistical observation that is markedly different in value from the others of the sample

Answer (score 1):

If you want to refer to things that *break* the rule, i.e. that are over 200lb, then you could say they *offend*.

> *These are all the offending objects*

Definition from the [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/offending):

> **Offend**
>
> - To violate a rule or law: *offended against the curfew.*

Answer (score 1):

Although someone has answered "non-conforming", your question itself asks for a word to describe the objects that do not comply with the rule.

Therefore, I suggest non-compliant.